# How is the B-Tree created for a composite PK?

Tags: sql-server

This is a theoretical question in regards to how SQL Server stores the data for a table that has a **clustered index over two columns (both columns form a PK)**. Consider a table with columns `PersonID`, `PersonAge` and `Name`. I have a clustered index on the two columns: `(PersonID, PersonAge)`.

How is the information stored using the index (B-Tree)? When I query this, only `PersonID` was sorted physically and `PersonAge` was left out (not sorted). Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

** Please do not give design recommendations, this is a theoretical question. **

Comment: `When I query this, only PersonID was sorted physically and PersonAge was left out (not sorted)` – what specifically do you do when you are trying to determine that?

Comment: Here is one way to find out how the rows are sorted in the clustered key. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6a6aa/1). Have a look at the generated execution plans and see that the second query has to sort the rows to generate the correct output where the first does not.

Comment: A few more examples [SQL Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6a6aa/4) that require no sort.

Comment: The index is logically ordered in exactly the same order as an `ORDER BY PersonID, PersonAge` would give. So `PersonAge` only makes any difference to ordering where rows are tied with the same id.

Comment: Thanks for all of the contributions guys... I see your examples on SQL Fidlle, but I just don't see that in SQL Server... To be specific, I just queried from my tables, expecting a first sort on PersonID, and a second sort on PersonAge (or vice versa).. but I only got the PersonID sorted. what I'll do is that I will examine the execution plan ...

Comment: Guys, thanks for showing me how to verify this. I think knowing how to verify this (via looking out for the SORT on the execution plan as opposed to just SELECT it and hoping to see sorted results) is worth being an "answer". If one of you puts that into an answer, I'll vote it as CORRECT.

Comment: What exactly were you looking for? Did you expect the results to be ordered by the clustered index when you don't supply an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @ypercube yes, that's exactly what I was expecting because the rows have to be EITHER physically OR logically sorted. Either way, the displayed rows should have been sorted first by ID then by Age... which didn't happen. However, when I used "ORDER BY", there was no "sort" function in my exec plan.

Comment: The rows are returned - in almost all DBMS - in arbitrary order. Unless you specifically provide an `ORDER BY` in the external level of the query.